# what's wrong with my code in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I try to write a program that asks the user for his name and greets the user with his name. The error is comma, colon or end of line expected. How can I correct this? I can't figure out where I'm gonna make corrections.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
 MES DB 10,13,'ENTER A STRING:$'
 BUF DB 255,256, DUP, (0)
 MES1 DB 10,13,'HELLO  $'

segment .text
global _asm_main
_asm_main:

enter 0,0
pusha

       MOV AX,DATA
       MOV DS,AX                 
       MOV AH,09H                

       LEA DX,MES
       INT 21H

       MOV AH,0aH                
       LEA DX,BUF
       INT 21H

       MOV AH,09H                
       LEA DX,buf
       INT 21H

       LEA SI,BUF              

       MOV AX,0
       MOV AL,BYTE PTR [SI]
       ADD SI,AX
       MOV BYTE PTR [SI+1],'$' 


       MOV AH,09H
       LEA DX,BUF+2
       INT 21H

       MOV AX,4C00H
       INT 21H

       popa

mov ax, 0
leave
ret
```

Comment: Correct _what_? You haven't described what the problem with your current code is.

Comment: The error is comma, colon or end of line expected on line 34 and 36

Comment: May be a problem with the syntax of indirect addressing in `BYTE PTR [SI]`and `BYTE PTR [SI+1]`. What assembler are you using?

Comment: I'm using nasm @zx485

Comment: In this line you need to drop the last two commas. `BUF DB 255,256, DUP, (0)`

Answer (score 1):

`BYTE PTR` is MASM/TASM syntax. The code you've posted looks (mostly) like it's written for NASM so you should drop the `PTR` (i.e. use `MOV AL, BYTE [SI]`, etc).

Comment: Many error again. I can't figure out the correct code. :(

Comment: Well, stuff like `LEA DX,BUF+2` isn't valid NASM syntax. Don't use a TASM/MASM-oriented tutorial if you intend to use NASM.

Comment: The size of the memory access is already specified with the AL-register, so we do not needed for to use "byte" or "byte ptr". i.e. use `MOV AL, [SI]`. But for a memmory acces with a immediate operand we need to use it. Example: `MOV BYTE [SI+1],'$'`